# Split a CSV row into multiple rows based on cell value

Tags: linux, csv

I have a CSV file with data that is formatted like this. I want to split the rows X number of times where X is defined by column 3.

FRUIT,BANANA,3
FRUIT,LEMON,1
FRUIT,ORANGE,2

The output should look like this.

FRUIT,BANANA,1
FRUIT,BANANA,1
FRUIT,BANANA,1
FRUIT,LEMON,1
FRUIT,ORANGE,1
FRUIT,ORANGE,1

Is there an easy way to accomplish this in Linux using awk or similar program?

Comment: Yes! Hmm, maybe... Linux is just an OS but many tools are available. It is trivial if you can use high level script tools like Python, Perl or Ruby, it is possible with only the standard tools and shell, maybe a little harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with `awk`:

```
awk -F , -v "OFS=," '{ for(i=0; i<$3; i++) print $1,$2,1; }' inputfile
```

Explanation: `-F ,` and `-v "OFS=,"` set field separators for input and output. The loop prints individual columns.

Alternative:

```
 awk -F , -v "OFS=," '{ i=$3;$3=1;for(; i>0; i--) print; }' inputfile
```

Here column 3 is modified before the loop prints the whole record/line.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need awk, just the shell:

```bash
data() {
  cat <<EOF
FRUIT,BANANA,3
FRUIT,LEMON,1
FRUIT,ORANGE,2
EOF
}

data | while IFS=, read -r field fruit n ; do
  for i in $(seq 1 $n) ; do
    echo "$field,$fruit,1"
  done
done
```

Explanation:

- The line `IFS=, read -r field fruit n` changes the internal field separator (IFS) to a comma and the reads the line into variables field, fruit and n.
- The line `for i in $(seq 1 $n)` iterates for each i in 1 to n.